# update with foreign key constrain

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

how to update multiple tuples which are linked with foreign key constraint
here is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    driverId VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    driverName VARCHAR(30),
    address VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE car
(
    regNo VARCHAR(10),
    model VARCHAR(25),
    YEAR INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(regNo)
);


CREATE TABLE accident 
(
    reportNo INT,
    accidentDate DATE,
    location VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(reportNo)
);

CREATE TABLE participated
(
    driverId VARCHAR(10),
    regNo VARCHAR(10) ,
    reportNo INT,
    damageAmount INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(driverId) REFERENCES person(driverId),
    FOREIGN KEY(regNo) REFERENCES car(regNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(reportNo) REFERENCES accident(reportNo),
    PRIMARY KEY(driverId, regNo,reportNo)
);

CREATE TABLE owns
(
    driverId VARCHAR(10),
    regNo VARCHAR(10),
    FOREIGN KEY(driverId) REFERENCES person(driverId),
    FOREIGN KEY(regNo) REFERENCES car(regNo),
    PRIMARY KEY(driverId, regNo)
);
```

when i'm executing this command

```
UPDATE accident
SET reportNo=5555
WHERE reportNo=2222;
```

the tuples with same "reportNo" in the "PARTICIPATED" table are not being updated

Comment: Each table needs to be `InnoDB`.

Comment: @njk so what is syntax for making table innodb

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html

Comment: @IanO.S.  how to update the original myisam table to innodb

Comment: @JW no errors its updating each individual table only

Comment: @tiger `ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: @njk tried both on cascade and innodb method still not global update is happening

Answer (score 0):

try adding `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the foreign key constraint in the participated table

Answer (score 0):

1. Your database engine must be `InnoDB`. You can alter the engine using:

   `ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;`
2. If no referential action is specified, the default action is to restrict. You must specify `ON DELETE` or `ON UPDATE` actions. [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

use following query.

        **ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FOREIGN KEY(keyname) references parent_table_name.column  name on update cascade on delete cascade.**

Cascading allows the changes in parent table to be reflected in child tables.
but make sure your storage engine must be InnoDB